# Why is my function not running properly in my local host but works perfectly fine in an online web editor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, drawing, p5.js

I am creating a drawing application and using P5.JS for it. All the different tools have different constructor functions and while other tools work completely fine, my flood fill tool is giving me a hard time. I have it working in my web editor and it works fine over there but when I try and copy it onto my constructor function, things don't seem to work. I keep on just drawing a single line of pixels on the canvas. Here is the link to my Web Editor work which works perfectly fine: https://editor.p5js.org/aheedshah/sketches/3-9QQWHjN 
 
And here is the code I'm using for my constructor function.

```
let stack = []; //Creating an empty stack global variable
let oldColor; //Checks the old colour of the shape
let fillColor; //Fills the shape clicked on with this colour

function FloodFill() {
    //Setting the name and icon
    this.name = "floodFill";
    this.icon = "assets/floodFill.jpg";

    noSmooth(); //Draws all geometry with jagged edges. Reference: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noSmooth

    this.draw = function() {
        this.mouseClicked();
        fillColor = color(0, 255, 0); //Setting the fill colour to green
        this.matches = function(c, x, y) {
            return JSON.stringify(get(x, y)) === JSON.stringify(c);
        }
          
        if (!stack.length) {
            return;
        }
        
        let p = stack.pop();
        let x1 = p.x;
        let y = p.y;
          
        while (x1 > 0 && this.matches(oldColor, x1 - 1, y)) {
            x1--;
        }
        
        let spanAbove = false;
        let spanBelow = false;
        
        for (let x2 = x1 + 1; x2 < width && this.matches(oldColor, x2, y); ++x2) {
            set(x2, y, fillColor);
            if (y > 0 && spanAbove !== this.matches(oldColor, x2, y - 1)) {
                if (!spanAbove)
                    stack.push({ x: x2, y: y - 1 });
                spanAbove = !spanAbove;
            }
            if (y < height - 1 && spanBelow !== this.matches(oldColor, x2, y + 1)) {
                if (!spanBelow)
                    stack.push({ x: x2, y: y + 1 });
                spanBelow = !spanBelow;
            }
        }
        updatePixels();
    }
    this.mouseClicked = function() {
        if(keyIsDown(SHIFT)) {
            oldColor = get(mouseX, mouseY);
            loadPixels();
            stack = [];
            stack.push({x: mouseX, y: mouseY});  
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the code above seems to draw only a **single line** of pixels of yellow colour. Things like the canvas aren't created in this file because they are already created on a separate sketch file which is where I call my constructor function as well.
All the help is much appreciated.

Comment: If there is a single canvas, does it work properly?

Comment: There is a single canvas in both of these examples

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example of the issue. StackOverflow has snippet functionality where you can embed runnable HTML & Javascript so that people can easily reproduce the issue. As it stands the code in your question doesn't seem like it has anything to do with the linked p5js Web Editor code, and also cannot be readily run as-is on a local machine.

Comment: I should rephrase: "code in your question seems *significantly different* than the linked p5js Web Editor code"

Comment: Calling `this.mouseClicked();` in your `draw()` function seems like a strange thing to do since that is going to reset your stack if the user is still holding down the shift key.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be because you are referencing a local directory, (assets/floodfill)? the file might not be accessible when running from your home computer, but have already been uploaded to the p5.js web editor?